# rails server does not start on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, rubygems

I'm newbie to ruby on rails, I have created project but when I start server (rails server / s ) it gives me error. which is [image show you an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ycqG.png)

secondly when I run command "bundle install" it gives me another error which is [image show you second error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9z2S.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you figure out the server [openssl](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) issue which appears to show up in the `bundle install` output as well.